# Specify view and layout when adding a button with addNew()

Tags: view

I'm adding a button to the toolbar using

```
JToolBarHelper::addNew('thing.add');
```

I want it to have the same effect as clicking on the following menu button:

```
    <menu
        view="thing"
        layout="add"
        img="class:banners"
        alt="Add thing"
        >
        Add thing
    </menu>
```

Is this possible? Seems like `addNew` cannot be used to use a view from another controller? I can get the button to use the method `add` from controller `thing`, but not to use view `add` from `thing`.

**Edit**: Fixed by messing around with controller/model naming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buttons point to a method in your controller. So create a method inside your thing controller called add and then use a redirect to send it to your correct view/layout.

If you are using standard Joomla MVC patterns the thing.add should take you to the edit layout of your view with an ID of 0.